# Hyperlink doesn't answer

Tags: hyperref, links

In my output PDF, `\href` seems not to work. I generate a PDF file, using pdfLaTeX, and in the compiled file the link doesn't connect to the Web site. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}


\pagestyle{empty}   
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 


% required packages 
\usepackage{flowfram}                                   
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       
\usepackage{url}                                            
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}                
\usepackage{multicol}
        \setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{tikz}
\frenchspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Create column layout
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define length commands
\setlength{\vcolumnsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\columnsep}{\vcolumnsep}

% frame setup (flowfram package)
% left frame
% left frame
\newflowframe{0.2\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[left]
        \newlength{\LeftMainSep}
        \setlength{\LeftMainSep}{0.2\textwidth}
        \addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}

% small static frame for the vertical line
\newstaticframe{1.5pt}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}

% content of the static frame
\begin{staticcontents}{1}
\hfill
\tikz{%
        \draw[loosely dotted,color=RoyalBlue,line width=1.5pt,yshift=0]
        (0,0) -- (0,\textheight);}%
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{staticcontents}

% right frame
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1.5pt}
\addtolength{\LeftMainSep}{1\columnsep}
\newflowframe{0.7\textwidth}{\textheight}{\LeftMainSep}{0pt}[main01]
% horizontal rule between frames (using TikZ)
\renewcommand{\ffvrule}[3]{%
\hfill
\tikz{%
        \draw[loosely dotted,color=Orange,line width=1.5pt,yshift=-#1] 
        (0,0) -- (0pt,#3);}%
\hfill\mbox{}}
\insertvrule{flow}{1}{flow}{2}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define macros (for convience)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\Sep}{\vspace{1.5em}}
\newcommand{\SmallSep}{\vspace{0.5em}}

\newenvironment{OMnie}
        {\ignorespaces{\color{RoyalBlue} O Sobie}}
        {\Sep\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\CVSection}[1]
        {\Large\textbf{#1}\par
        \SmallSep\normalsize\normalfont}

\newcommand{\CVItem}[1]
{\textbf{\color{RoyalBlue} #1}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{   
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=black,
        filecolor=black,
        linkcolor=gray,
        urlcolor=orange,
        pdftex
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Left frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
        \hfill
        %\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{daniel}
        \vspace{-7cm}
\end{figure}

\begin{flushright}\small
        Daniel Miliński \\
        \href{mailto:daniel_milinski@o2.pl}        {\nolinkurl{daniel_milinski@o2.pl}}  \\
        \url{www.kognitywistyka.net} \\
        (791) 26 05 29
\end{flushright}\normalsize
\framebreak


% Right frame
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Huge\bfseries{\color{RoyalBlue} Daniel Miliński} \\
\Large\bfseries  Kognitywista \
\normalsize\normalfont

\begin{OMnie}
\href{http://kcp.krakow.pl}{KCP}
Kognitywisci stanowią -- ludzie chcą się nauczyć myśleć jak mszyny, m y próbujemy [po więcej informacji na temat: Czym jest Kognitwistyka?
Multydyscyplinaren wykształcenie pozwala na 
\href{http://kognitywistyka.net}{go to button}


\end{OMnie}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say `\url{www.kognitywistyka.net}`, `hyperref` is not able to know what kind of link you're declaring.

I'd input the address as

```
\begin{flushright}\small
Daniel Miliński \\
\footnotesize
  \ignorewidth{\href{mailto:daniel_milinski@o2.pl}{\nolinkurl{daniel_milinski@o2.pl}}}  \\
  \ignorewidth{\href{http://www.kognitywistyka.net}{\nolinkurl{www.kognitywistyka.net}}} \\
(791) 26 05 29
\end{flushright}
```

so it stays on four lines. The `\ignorewidth` command is defined as

```
\newcommand{\ignorewidth}[2][r]{\makebox[0pt][#1]{#2}}
```

which you should add in your preamble.

Comment: It still dosen't anser in a pdf document. Ansers in a document in TeXStudio [after pdfLateX] but not in a direct file [in which i'm interested].

Comment: Thank You for Your time and attitude. I tried it, and it works fine, but only in a TeX studio viewer. It dosen't work from hard drive.

Comment: What do you mean "from hard drive"?