# URL doesn't work in header

Tags: hyperref, header-footer, fancyhdr, urls

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[MeX]{polski}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{#1.\hskip0.7em}
\makeatother


\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{{\small Krakowskie Centrum Psychodynamiczne\\
\url{www.kcp.krakow.pl}}}
\fancyhead[L]{{\small Diagnoza strukturalna cz. I\\Otto F. Kernberg}}
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
{
 \fancyhead{}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt} % pozioma kreska
}

%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup
{   
 colorlinks,
 citecolor=black,
 filecolor=black,
 linkcolor=black,
 urlcolor=black,
 pdftex
}

\frenchspacing




\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

All time I have problems whit `hyperref`. Doesn't matter what I do, it still doesn't work. Any suggestions why is that? What, exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: The method I suggested in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59831/4427) works for me. Please precise what "doesn't work".

Comment: After I genreted a pdf, a when I go to the TeXStudio View I click on a hiperlink and it does work. But when I open a normal pdf, from my hard memory - after a click on a link, nothing happen. What is most important, when I download a pdf[Latex one] from a web, and there is a hiperlink inside this document -- it does work, so my pdf viewer works fine. So I wonder, what is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but Paulo Cereda helped testing the example with my suggested syntax and it works on a GNU/Linux box and on Windows, other than on Mac OS X (this is where I tested).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to write

```
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \small Krakowskie Centrum Psychodynamiczne\\
  \href{http://www.kcp.krakow.pl}{\nolinkurl{www.kcp.krakow.pl}}%
}
```

that will print only `www.kcp.krakow.pl` but will refer internally to `http://www.kcp.krakow.pl`.

You can check that it's considered indeed a URL by changing the option

```
urlcolor=red
```

and see that `www.kcp.krakow.pl` appears in red.

As an aside, put also

```
\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}
```

in your preamble, to ensure correct positioning of the header.